# how reverse relation works in django model while working with serializers?

Tags: python, django

here is my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles
from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_by_name
from pygments.formatters.html import HtmlFormatter
from pygments import highlight


LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted((item, item) for item in get_all_styles())


class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python', max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly', max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('User')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

here is my seralizers.py

```
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from .models import Snippet
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import permissions
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.user')
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = '__all__'

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    snippets = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Snippet.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

here is my view.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse

from .models import *
from .serializers import *
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status,mixins,generics
from django.http import Http404


class SnippetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)


class SnippetDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer

class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from api.models import *
from api import views
from api.serializers import UserSerializer


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^snippets/$', views.SnippetList.as_view()),
    url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.SnippetDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^users/$', views.UserList.as_view()),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.UserDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
]
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

i wants to get owner name in snippets as it is defined as foreign key in Snippet model and 
again wnats to get all snippets details in the User.

expected snippets should be like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "created": "2018-09-23T06:05:15.416966Z",
        "title": "hello code",
        "code": "print -< \"hello\"",
        "linenos": false,
        "language": "python",
        "style": "friendly",
        "owner": "soubhagya"
    }
]
```

expected user should be like this

```
    [
        {
            "name":"soubhagya",
            "snippets": [
                "id": 1,
                "created": "2018-09-23T06:05:15.416966Z",
                "title": "hello code",
                "code": "print -< \"hello\"",
                "linenos": false,
                "language": "python",
                "style": "friendly",
            ]
        }
    ]
```

how to get the data as per these two samples..

Comment: Are you asking us to write some code for you? We fix code for you here, we don't write it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong serializer for the relationship. Have you read [this documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)? It is a really good introduction and shows you both fields you need:

- [StringRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield) for the username in a snippet.
- [Nested relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) for the snippets in the user

Your user model already has the correct `__str__` method, returning `self.name`, so you should get this working quite easy.

But, don't use the SnippetSerializer for the nested one, since it will once again put the owner in there. Instead, write a second serializer that does not include the owner field. When you have that working, refactor and put the common fields on one serializer, then add the owner field to the second serializer by extending it, so you keep it DRY.